# "AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall is not a function"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am fairly new to aws & typescript. I was adding the AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall function to convert DynamoDBStream object to Javascript object. But I am getting the compile time error "AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall is not a function". 
I have added the aws sdk as import.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk"
let newImage: IDBEventItem;
                    try {
                        newImage = <IDBEventItem>AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(record.dynamodb.NewImage);
                    } catch (ex) {
                        ctx.logger.error("error with unmarshal", ex);
                        return accumulator;
                    }
```

any pointers on this issue will be of great help.

thanks

Comment: Please post the code that you want to have reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue. I did not manage to see when thoses functions were added but they seems to be recent.

You need to update your aws-sdk version doing:

```
yarn add aws-sdk
```

or

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

From aws-sdk ^2.49.0 version to ^2.243.1

This solved my problem.